# What is the word for the description below

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Declining someone for a reason besides the primary reason. Like rejecting help for a reason other than the reason that they don't need help.
So basically how would I rephrase this sentence: The women thought I declined her offer because of her appearance and the state of the situation however I declined due to not needing help.

The woman thinking "I declined her for reasons not relating to the question" sat melancholic.

Comment: What is the word for that in your native language?

Comment: bheja kai mate me na bholu

Comment: That looks like six words, Pranjal.

Comment: ya, but I thought there might be a concise way to say it in English or at least more concise than the sentence I have.

Comment: I think you've expressed a complex idea in your question. I wouldn't expect a simple expression to summarize it. The only thing I can of to say is that "she may be hurt because she misunderstood your intentions."

Comment: 1. You don't decline someone, you decline an offer or an opportunity. 2. Women is plural; we do not say a women, but rather a woman.